# Adjective meaning "likely to be chased after" or "susceptible to getting chased"?

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms, adjectives

In the sentence

> Don't wear that, you are very ______. The bears will chase you.

Is *chaseable* a word? Would it fit the sentence?

Not a native speaker.

Comment: Chasable [is a word](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Chasable), albeit not a very common one. You could paraphrase and say that "it's like painting a bullseye on your back", or "it's like wearing a neon sign", to imply they stick out.

Comment: @TusharRaj However, that word is used in a diametrically opposite reference of transitivity :)

Comment: @Kris: If a human is hunting a bear, the bear is chasable ("fit for hunting"); if a bear is hunting a human, like the OP suggested, the human is chasable. I don't see your point.

Comment: @TusharRaj Oh they do! :)

Comment: @TusharRaj "chasable" means capable of being chased, which is not the same as *likely* to be chased.

Comment: I might start with this thesaurus entry for [tempting](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/tempting?s=t).  My own favorite is alluring.  YMMV.

Comment: For a noun I would say "prey".  Don't know of an equivalent adjective, offhand.

Comment: Ah, yes!  The adjective would be "tasty".

Answer (score 2):

It's not specific to being chased, but I think somewords that fit the example sentence are [**noticeable**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/noticeable)

> Easily seen or noticed; clear or apparent

or [**conspicuous**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/conspicuous)

> Attracting notice or attention

Being noticed by the bears leads to them being likely to chase you, and the causative link is obvious. I don't think there's a word that's more specific to the chase implication.

Comment: Also, provocative, as pushing or inciting the bear to give chase.

Answer (score 0):

> Don't wear that, you are very ***eye-catching***. The bears will chase
>   you.

M-W:

> **[eye-catching](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eye-catching)**
>   *adjective*
>
> :  very noticeable because of being unusual or attractive
>   The movie
>   features eye-catching special effects; eye-catching colors/styles